# CDI - Java EE Servlet saving variables to a managed bean

Tags: html, jakarta-ee, cdi

I have a Java EE class that currently reads info from a form and prints it out.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Response extends HttpServlet
{
    String date = "0";

    public void init() throws ServletException 
    {
        //Get Election Date from xml
        String initial = getInitParameter("electionDate");
        date = initial;
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        //Get values from form
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        String firstName=request.getParameter("firstname");  
        String lastName=request.getParameter("lastname");  
        String address=request.getParameter("address");  
        String city=request.getParameter("city");  
        String state=request.getParameter("state");  
        String zip=request.getParameter("zip");  
        String phone = request.getParameter("phone"); 
        String affil=request.getParameter("affil");

        //Print Summary of Voter Registration
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head><title>Registration Summary</title></head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<p>Registration Summmary</p>"); 
        out.println("<p>First Name: " + firstName + "</p>");
        out.println("<p>Last Name: " + lastName + "</p>"); 
        out.println("<p>Address : " + address + "</p>"); 
        out.println("<p>City : " + city + "</p>");
        out.println("<p>State : " + state + "</p>");
        out.println("<p>Zip: " + zip + "</p>");
        out.println("<p>Phone Number: " + phone + "</p>"); 
        out.println("<p>Affiliation: " + affil + "</p>"); 
        out.println("<p>Next Election Date: " + date + "</p></p>");

        out.println("<p>Is the above information correct?</p>"); 
        out.println("<button>Yes</button>"); 
        out.println("<button>No</button>"); 

        out.println("</body></html>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I want to get the values (firstName, lastName, etc.) from this Java servlet and inject to a bean.

Then when this file calls another servlet I want the values from the bean to be available in that servlet.

I just want to know how to store the variables I created above into a managed bean and then have the other servlet reference and retrieve the variables in that bean.

I have beans.xml, web.xml, pom.xml (I'm using Maven) files set up already.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply inject Strings, so you will have to use a qualifier (the simplest one is @Named, see if that is sufficient).

In your servlet, say

```
@Produces
@Named("foo")
String lastName;
...
void doPost() {
  lastName = getParameter(...);
}
```

and in the target bean, use

```
@Inject
@Named("foo")
String lastName;
```

Since you are in a Request-Scope, keep in mind that injecting request-scoped values into longer living instances (EJBs for example) might lead to unpredictable behavior. I seriously doubt that your approach will make you happy. Perhaps you could tell us more about what you are trying to do?